# Searching in the gridview + storing in the variable

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox, button and a gridview. The gridview will display the username depending on the email address written in the textbox. I want to store this username in a variable. How can i do tht? If there are many usernames in the gridview, i want to store then in an array. How can I do that too?

Comment: If you know how to get the username from the email, why don't you know how to store it in a variable? How do you get the username(s) from the email?

Comment: please make clear and provide some code

Comment: I have configured the gridview with a datasourse by using email in the WHERE clause. Here I'm not selecting any row of the gridview.If I had selected the gridview then definitely I would have written as gridview1.selected.rows. Thats why I'm confused how to put that value in the variable

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string Users = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
        }
   }
```

U can store these details in database by writing insert statements inside for loop